# Tracking System function (Get) calls, and Stack[_]

Tags: evaluation, scoping

Consider the following attempt and variations thereof to track (nested) calls to [`Get`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html) (reasoning of this approach below):

```
Unprotect[Get];

trackGet[rule_] := (
  Clear@Get;
  i = 0; (* to prevent infinite recursion in some of the broken attempts*)
  Hold[ (* hold definition until it has been modified *)
    Get[file_] := With[
      {s = Stack[_]},
      wrapper[Get[Echo[file]]] /; ++i <= 3 (* prevent infinite recursion *) && 
       (
         Echo@Length@EchoFunction[Shallow]@s < 3 ||
          (* the core part: check the stack entry three layers up
            to prevent calling ourselves *)
           s[[-3]] =!= HoldForm[wrapper[Get[Echo[file]]]]
       )
    ]
  ] /. rule // ReleaseHold (* modify definition to show different cases *)
)

Print@"Version 1";
trackGet[wrapper[x_] :> Block[{}, x]]
<< GeneralUtilities`

Print@"Version 2";
trackGet[wrapper[x_] :> With[{}, x]]
<< GeneralUtilities`

Print@"Version 3";
trackGet[wrapper[x_] :> x]
<< GeneralUtilities`

(* Version 1 *)
(* {Get[<<1>>],With[<<2>>]} *)
(* 2 *)
(* GeneralUtilities` *)
(* {Block[<<2>>],Get[<<1>>],With[<<2>>]} *)
(* 3 *)
(* {Block[<<2>>],Get[<<1>>],Get[<<1>>],With[<<2>>]} *)
(* 4 *)
(* GeneralUtilitiesLoader` *)

(* Version 2 *)
(* {Get[<<1>>],With[<<2>>]} *)
(* 2 *)
(* GeneralUtilities` *)
(* {Get[<<1>>],With[<<2>>]} *)
(* 2 *)
(* GeneralUtilities` *)
(* {Get[<<1>>],With[<<2>>]} *)
(* 2 *)
(* GeneralUtilities` *)

(* Version 3 *)
(* {Get[<<1>>],With[<<2>>]} *)
(* 2 *)
(* GeneralUtilities` *)
(* {Get[<<1>>],With[<<2>>]} *)
(* 2 *)
(* GeneralUtilities` *)
(* {Get[<<1>>],With[<<2>>]} *)
(* 2 *)
(* GeneralUtilities` *)
```

First a bit about what I try to achieve with this: The goal is to track any call to `Get[_]` - but since I need to track nested calls, I can't use the [Villegas-Gayley trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656/3032376). The idea of this approach is to inspect the last few layers of the `Stack[_]` to prevent the function from directly calling itself (but deeper nested calls are allowed again).

A bit on `trackGet` from above: The general structure is

```
Get[file_] := With[
  {s = Stack[_]},
  wrapper[Get[Echo[file]]]/;(*stackCheck*)
]
```

For the three versions, the `wrapper` is either: `Block[{}, ...]` (Version 1), `With[{}, ...]` (Version 2), or nothing (Version 3).

**The question now:** Why do the outputs of the three version differ in the way they do, i.e. why does an empty `Block` work, but `With` or nothing does not?

A few observations:

- The wrapper is inside the [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html), so any of the special handling of `lhs_:>With[{vars},res/;cond]` does not apply. (And if it did, `Block` and `With` should both work according to the documentation)
- The stack returned by `Stack[_]` only sees my definition of `Get`, everything else is not shown.
- The stack only gets longer for the case with `Block`, the other two are always the same length (see the numbers in the output) - this seems to be the reason why only the `Block` variant works
- *Update*: I did a few more tests and it seems most functions work in place of `Block` (e.g. `CompoundExpression`) - the only exceptions I've found so far is no wrapper and `With`. I'm assuming that somehow "trivial" definitions are not shown in the stack (for system functions at least), where "trivial" seems to be able to handle `With` transparently, but not `Block` or other functions

Comment: Look at ``Internal`HandlerBlock`` if you just want to track `Get`

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks a lot! This solves my original problem perfectly. But I'm still curios whether anyone knows what's going on in my attempt :)